# self-reference table entity framework insert record?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

**Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.**

ASP.NET MVC3 Entity framework 4.1

My MODEL

```
public class OrganizationStructure
{
    public OrganizationStructure()
    {
        this.OrganizationStructures = new List<OrganizationStructure>();

        InputDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int OrganizationStructureID { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationID { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationTypeID { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationActivityID { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationLocationID { get; set; }

    public string AddRemark { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime InputDate { get; set; }
    public int? RemAttr { get; set; }

    public IList<OrganizationStructure> OrganizationStructures { get; private set; }

}
```

### TABLE

ID  int Unchecked

Name    nvarchar(MAX)   Checked

OrganizationID  int Checked

OrganizationStructureID int Unchecked

OrganizationTypeID  int Checked

OrganizationLocationID  int Checked

OrganizationActivityID  int Checked

AddRemark   nvarchar(MAX)   Checked

UserId  int Checked

InputDate   datetime    Checked

RemAttr int Checked

```
public ICommandResult Execute(CreateOrUpdateOrganizationStructureCommand command)
{
    var organizationStructure = new OrganizationStructure
    {
        ID = command.ID,
        Name = command.Name,

        OrganizationStructureID = command.OrganizationStructureID,
        OrganizationID = command.OrganizationID,
        OrganizationTypeID = command.OrganizationTypeID,
        OrganizationActivityID = command.OrganizationActivityID,
        OrganizationLocationID = command.OrganizationLocationID,

        AddRemark = command.AddRemark,
        UserId = command.UserId
    };
    if (organizationStructure.ID == 0)
        _organizationStructureRepository.Add(organizationStructure);
    else
        _organizationStructureRepository.Update(organizationStructure);
    _unitOfWork.Commit();
    return new CommandResult(true);
}
```

Comment: That is not very useful update because the relevant code is probably inside that repository ...

Answer (score 1):

The `OrganizationStructureID` property has to be nullable otherwise you will not be able to insert records with auto incremented primary keys.

EF will not be able to handle cyclic relationship even if you had `OrganizationStructureID` nullable. You need to save it in 2 steps.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
     var context = new MyContext();
     var organizationStructure = new OrganizationStructure {/* assign props */ };
     context.OrganizationStructures.Add(organizationStructure);

     context.SaveChanges(); // step 1

     organizationStructure.OrganizationStructures.Add(organizationStructure);

     context.SaveChanges(); // step 2

     scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: I updated question. CreateOrUpdateOrganizationStructure handler